# Difference between "am doing", "will be doing", and "will do"

Tags: future-constructions

> I **am doing** your homework on Monday.

> I **will be doing** your homework on Monday.

> I **will do** your homework on Monday.

What is the difference between the three with respect to future meaning?

Comment: I am doing - I have a plan to do the homework; will be doing - I will be in a process of doing it; will do - in my own opinion and because of my own wish I hope that I start doing your homework on Monday

Comment: _I will do your homework_ sounds like an offer or promise to do it.